# How to install Kafka Connector **Manually** in Mule Any point Studio 7x?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule4

How to install Kafka connector ***manually*** in Mule Any Point Studio 7X ? We don't have internet access from Remote server, So everything needs to installed manually. I can download kafka connector from Mule Soft site but not sure how to install connector as.jar file.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Anypoint Studio 7.x/Mule 4.x connectors are not installed into Studio as in previous versions. They are Maven dependencies, because all Mule 4.x projects are Maven based. So the problem is to install the Maven dependency for the Mule 4 Kafka connector into your local Maven directory. This is done automatically by Maven when building a project assuming there is internet access. In your case there is no internet access, that is the way Maven expects to work. You can try one of the following alternatives, but neither is perfect for every scenario:

- (Recommended) Install a Maven proxy: some Maven servers support working as proxies
  of other repositories. It would need internet access, and you have to
  configure your settings.xml to use the server as a proxy, instead of
  accessing the internet directly. Your company would have to allow
  internet access for the proxy. This method is the more simpler to use once the setup is done. You don't need to do anything for new releases of dependencies. Having said that the new server will require some administration.
- Install the jar dependency in the
  local repository: if you have the jar file for the connector you can
  try to install it locally with the command `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>`. Note that connectors are like other Maven dependencies and have their own dependencies. You will have to be
  sure to add those dependencies too for the build to work. You will
  need to repeat this process every time there is a new release that
  you want to use. The command to install a dependency from a jar built from Maven works in recent versions of Maven. If using an older version -not recommended- you will have to use a less convenient alternative: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html
- Copy the local repository dependencies from another
  computer: build a project with the Kafka connector from a computer
  with access to internet, then copy the dependencies from the local
  repository (Linux/mac: `~/.m2/repository`, Windows:
  `%USERPROFILE%\.m2` to your restricted computer. Note that copying
  the entire repository might override dependencies that were installed
  manually. You might want to cherry pick the dependencies of the
  connector and copy those directories only. You will need to repeat
  this process every time there is a new release that you want to use.

The connector will not be visible in Studio palette until you add it to the project, by adding its dependency to the pom.xml file of the project as documented at https://docs.mulesoft.com/kafka-connector/4.4/kafka-connector-xml-maven#add-a-pom-file-dependency

Comment: Hi, i have copied required dependencies  to remote computer but still kafka connector showing up. Do i want to make any entry in the config files ?

Comment: Did you add the dependency in the pom.xml as mentioned in the documentation? https://docs.mulesoft.com/kafka-connector/4.4/kafka-connector-xml-maven#add-a-pom-file-dependency

Comment: Excellent, Thank you.

Comment: I added that step to the answer.